# Webpage automation

Tags: selenium, web, vbscript, browser-automation

I am trying to auto-fetch a screenshot on webpage using VBScript. I am stuck at a point where the VBScript is not able to identify an element which I need to click.

Is there any way to identify the element other elementId like `xpath/title/value/name` which are much more easily identified in Selenium webpage automation. Here is my script:

```
Dim IE
Dim Helem
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 
IE.navigate "https://mylink/logon.jsp"

Do While (IE.Busy)
   WScript.Sleep 3
Loop

Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("overridelink")
Helem.Click

Do While (IE.Busy)
   WScript.Sleep 3
Loop

Set Helem = IE.document.getElementById("j_username")
Helem.Value = "user123"
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementById("j_password")
Helem.Value = "pass123"
IE.document.getElementById("other").Click

Do While (IE.Busy)
   WScript.Sleep 10
Loop  

IE.document.getElementById("elementId").Click
```

The issue is occuring where the last element is not being idenified using Id. I'm getting the following error:

> Error : Object required :'document.getElementById(...)'
>   Code : 800A01A8

That's the demo I have used here. The frame coding on the page is :

```
<frameset id="Cmain" ////<br/>
    <FRAME id="Banner" //<br/>
    <frameset id="content" //<br/>
        <FRAME id="Navigation" //<br/>
        <frameset rows=//<br/>
            <FRAME id="Taskbar" //<br/>
            <FRAME id="Work"       //<br/>
            <FRAME id="Work_NonSM" //<br/>
        </frameset><br/>
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

The ID which I have used is "Navigation".

```
IE.document.parentWindow.window.frames(0).document.getElementById("element id")
```

Comment: Does the element actually have an ID? There really isn't much we can tell you without seeing the source of the page or an error message.

Comment: Actually there is a ID but its not being identified. The error message is coming in prompt after executing vbscript. Error :- Object required :'document.getElementById(...)' Code : 800A01A8

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `IE` handle got disconnected from the actual IE instance. Try re-attaching it:

```
...

Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each wnd In app.Windows
  If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set IE = wnd
    Exit For
  End If
Next

IE.document.getElementById("elementId").Click
```

If you have more than one Internet Explorer window you could use the window title instead of the executable name to select the correct one:

```
For Each wnd In app.Windows
  If InStr(1, wnd.LocationName, "page title", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set IE = wnd
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Comment: do i need to add this after the code where i am getting error means after i need click?

Comment: still i m getting the same error. I think the issue is caused by element not identified. Is there any other ways of identifying the element other than the getElementById like xpath

Comment: @rahnik67 If you can't get the element by ID, then an XPath expression won't help either. Does the page contain frames or iframes?

Comment: yes it has frames.. can we access the element through href component. ?

Comment: @rahnik67 Frames contain nested documents, i.e. they have `document` elements of their own, so you need something like `IE.document.parentWindow.window.frames(...).document.getElementById(...)`.

Comment: ok got the issue. but still i am not able to run the script. "parentWindow.window" object required error is still appearing. how to reach out to the frame..this is what i need currently

Comment: @rahnik67 Show your updated code (in your question) and the exact error you're getting. I'm not sitting in front of your computer.

Comment: @rahnik67 Is frame(0) the correct frame? How is the frameset defined?

Comment: i have added the frame set in the code. please note that i have used the "navigation" frame. The error is object required : document.parentWindow.window

Comment: i think its due to nested frames. Could you please tell me how we can access child frame element

Comment: @rahnik67 What you posted is invalid HTML. Please post the actual frameset.

Comment: can the windows propmpt box/pop up can be clicked using VBA?