# Download an image from website

Tags: powershell

I ran this powershell script to download an image from a website (to download it, certain steps had to be made, that's why I used IE navigate). I put a random string with a space between 4 and 4 characters.

But I get an error and it doesn't even start to fill the blank with the string:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
At E:\getbd.ps1:13 char:1
+ $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("text") | where { $.name -eq "words ...
```

Here is the code:

```
$url = "https://fakecaptcha.com"
$set = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".ToCharArray()
for($i=1; $i -le 4; $i++){
$result += $set | Get-Random}
$result += ' '
for($i=1; $i -le 4; $i++){
$result += $set | Get-Random}
$ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible = $true 
$ie.silent = $true 
$ie.Navigate( $url )
while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("text") | where { $.name -eq "words" }.value = $result
$generateBtn = $ie.Document.getElementsById('input') | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'submit' -and $_.Value -eq 'Create it now!'} 
$generateBtn.click() 
while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
$readyBtn = $ie.Document.getElementsById('input') | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'button' -and $_.Value -eq 'Your captcha is done! Please click here to view it!!'} 
$readyBtn.click() 
while( $wc.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
$downloadBtn = $ie.Document.getElementsById('input') | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'button' -and $_.Value -eq 'DOWNLOAD'} 
$downloadBtn.click()
while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
$source = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName('img') | Select-Object -ExpandProperty src  
$file = '$E:\bdlic\'+$result+'.jpg'
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source,$file)
while( $wc.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
$ie.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 syntax errors in that line:

```
$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("text") | where { $.name -eq "words" }.value = $result
#                                                   ^                   ^^^^^^
```

1. `$.Name`: The "current object" variable is `$_`, not just `$`.
2. `where {...}.value`: You cannot use dot-notation on the scriptblock of a `Where-Object` statement. You need to put the entire statement in a (sub)expression for that.

Change the line to this:

```
($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("text") | where { $_.name -eq "words" }).value = $result
```

Comment: I made some repairs and this is the new code portion where i get the same error :                                                                                       `$readyBtn = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | ?{$_.href -eq 'javascript:void(0)'}
$readyBtn.click()`

Comment: That's a different error (or rather, it has a different cause), and you probably need to [re-attach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32715806/1630171) to your IE instance after issuing the first `Click()`.